# Is a class with static members and a public constructor a static class?

Tags: c#

If I have a class that is not marked `static`, but it does have `static` member variables, does this make the class itself `static`? It's being used in code like it is, but it has a public constructor. I thought they can only have private constructors?

Also, in a web application in a web page I make a call to a static class and assign it to a static member variable to be used in the page. If a user leaves the page will the static member variable remain in memory? I'm thinking just for the duration of that user's session, correct? Or would GC refrain from collecting it for some longer period of time?

Ok here's some code:

```
 public class CustomerManager
{

    private static MyFactory _customerFactory = MyFactory.GetInstance();

    public CustomerManager()
    { }

     public static List<CustUser> GetCustomersByWebRequest(int iClientID, string sEmployeeNumber)
```

It is being called in another class that is static like so:

```
 List<CustUser> customers = CustomerManager.GetCustomersByWebRequest(1, "23434");
```

and this is in production.

Comment: Your questions aren't clear, as you initially talk about a non-static class, and then refer to it as a static class...

Comment: Ok updated to reflect better understanding of non-static classes. :) Need clarification on memory management with web apps. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's entirely plausible for a non-static class to contain static members.

[Static classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx) don't have *any* instance constructors. Non-static classes have public instance constructors by default, but you can prevent instantiation "from the outside" with a private instance constructor.

EDIT: ASP.NET user sessions have little to do with memory management in .NET, unless some data is definitely stored in their session - which basically *just* acts as a strong reference to that object.

A static variable will prevent the object it refers to from being garbage collected while the `AppDomain` it's part of is still alive.

Regarding the `customers` variable - that will only prevent the `List<CustUser>` being garbage collected as long as the variable is considered "live" - and that will depend on what sort of variable it is and how it's being used.

Comment: static classes can have static private constructor. its called the first time the class is loaded to memory.

Comment: @Dani: That's not a constructor in the normal meaning of it though. When someone says "constructor" without specifying anything else, they pretty much always mean "instance constructor". Note that you can't give static constructors *any* access modifiers, including private, so "static private constructor" doesn't make much sense. Will edit to make this absolutely clear though...

Comment: Hi Jon I added some code to give you a better idea of what I mean.

Comment: Ok so after reading your response I have a non static class with static members and methods. Since the methods are static you would call it up just like the above code call does. Gotcha Now what about the memory management question?